# How can storyboard handle two segues for a table cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, master-detail

I'd like a master/detail kind of UI, but with the option of going to a different detail page depending on the data in the table cell. Can storyboards do this? If so, is there a tutorial or somewhere that explains? As an alternative, if I mix table cell types in the same table, can I define different detail pages that way?

Also, just an observation, does anyone find the Apple tutorials get very complicated very quickly? I'm having trouble trying to get through even with the first iOS app tutorial. So many control clicks and command drags and whatever and to non-intuitive targets. Like, who would expect a drag from a graphical element to a specific line in a source file? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm new to iOS development as well and I've been having good luck with [The iOS Apprentice](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice). Very easy to follow and explanations for everything being done (even the weird ctrl-clicks). I got it through work for free, otherwise I think it's $54. It looks like you can try the first 1 or 2 projects for free though.

Comment: I found out what was going on - two issues. The control-click-drag action doesn't work in Xcode 4.5, it's control-click like right-click to bring up a context menu, then drag to the screen. Also, there can't be any zoom applied to the storyboard, it must be at 100%. Three days working on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is didSelectRowAtIndexPath. In the .m file for the view controller you have your UITableView on, whenever the user clicks a row, it will trigger the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  Typically, you have an if block that checks which row was clicked, and does different things (like display different detail views).

As far as detailed tutorials, I find YouTube to be the easiest to learn from, especially for simple or common tasks. If you search for "Master-Detail Xcode" on there, I'm sure you'll find tons of results ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_J_r8AKw0k I think was one of the ones I found useful).

Comment: and yes, I find the Apple Docs to generally do more harm than good as a beginner.  There is a ton of detail and it's explained very thoroughly, but the language it uses seems like it was written for people that have been developing on Macs for years, and it's hard to find a quick answer if you don't know exactly what to search for.

Comment: and depending on how much time you have to learn, [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) looks very promising.  It's all the lectures from a prof for an intro course at Stanford, and it's all free on iTunes.  I haven't had the time to really start watching them yet, but I expect to learn a lot once I do.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your helpful advice. I'm just flummoxed why the designers of Xcode have a UI that's so user unfriendly. It's also not compatible with vision or mobility impaired users. If a major competitor (rhymes with krabbenhoft) were to do the same, they'd be raked over the coals. When Xcode settles down and matures, I'll probably write a book "Xcode for old Windows dudes".

Comment: I've been trying out the demos and for each of them I get to a certain point and because of differences in the versions (using Xcode 4.5) what I see starts to diverge from what is being described and I get completely lost. It's so frustrating. Xcode is stupefying in the literal sense - making me stupid.

Comment: haha preaching to the choir bro.  What made it even harder for me is I don't even really have any training in Object Oriented Programming - all my coding experience has been much more linear, primarily Fortran - and everything I've seen for tutorials assumes the reader is very familiar with the theories behind OOP, so it was hard enough to just wrap my head around classes, delegates, and about 100 other things, before even getting into the Xcode specific issues themselves.  And I'm sure that book would become a best seller, if Apple doesn't sue you for associating their product with Windows.